# Как записать значение массива в файл?

Tags: php

Как записать `["amount"]=> float(9)` а именно только значение 9 в файл?

Весь массив

```
 array(2) { [0]=> array(2) { ["amount"]=> float(9) ["currency"]=> int(643) } [1]=> NULL }
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file-put-contents.php

Comment: file_put_contents('path/to/file', $array['amount']);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С помощью [file_put_contents()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file-put-contents.php):

```
// $file - путь к файлу
// $array_res - массив
file_put_contents($file, $array_res[0]["amount"]);
```

С помощью [fwrite()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.fwrite.php)

```
// $file - путь к файлу
// $array_res - массив

// Открыть текстовый файл
$f = fopen($file, "w");
// Записать строку текста
fwrite($f, $array_res[0]["amount"]); 
// Закрыть текстовый файл
fclose($f);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

```
// Ваш массив будет в переменной $arr
$f = fopen("file.text", "w");
fwrite($f,  $arr[0]['amount']);
fclose($f);
```